# How to maintain all the changes made to Elasticsearch Mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

How do people maintain all the changes done to the elasticsearch index over time so that if I have re-built the elasticsearch index from scratch to be same as the existing one, I can just do so in minutes. Do people maintain the logs of all PUT calls made over time to update the mappings and other settings?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way is to use snapshot ,It's a backup taken from a running Elasticsearch cluster or index. You can take a snapshot of individual index or of the entire cluster and store it in a repository on a shared filesystem. It contains a copy of the on-disk data structures and mappings that make up an index beside that when you create a snapshot of an index Elasticsearch will avoid copying any data that is already stored in the repository as part of an earlier snapshot so you can build or recover an index from scratch to last version of taken snapshot very quickly.